# Solving $y=x+7\lceil\frac{x} {1113}\rceil$ for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, roots, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have a pretty simple formula:$$y=x+7\lceil\frac x {1113}\rceil ,$$but I do not know how to solve it for $x$.

For example, if $x$ is $5520$, $y$ will be $$5520+7\lceil\frac {5520} {1113}\rceil=5555 .$$Giving $5555$, I would like to have a formula returning $5520$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ceiling function is non-decreasing, and $x \mapsto x$ is strictly increasing, the function $f(x) = x+7\lceil\frac x {1113}\rceil$ is strictly increasing, hence it **is** injective.

However, it is **not** surjective, for example $f(0) = 0$, and for $x > 0$ we have$f(x) > 7$, hence $(0, 7]$ is not in the range of $f$.

In general, if $x = 1113n+\theta$, with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\theta \in (0,1113]$, we have $f(x) = f(1113n+ \theta) = 1113n + \theta+ 7n +7 = 1120 n+7 +\theta$. Since $f(1113n) = 1120n$, we see that $\operatorname{image} f = \left( \cup_{ n \in \mathbb{Z}} (1120n, 1120n+7] \right)^c$.

If $y \in E$, the inverse can be computed by setting $y = f(x)=f(1113n+\theta)$, with $\theta \in (0,1113]$. This gives the equation 
$ y=1120n+7+\theta$. This gives $\frac{y-7}{1120} = n + \frac{\theta}{1120}$, which gives $n = \lceil \frac{y-7}{1120} \rceil -1$ and $\theta = 1120(\frac{y-7}{1120}-\lceil \frac{y-7}{1120} \rceil +1)$, from which we get $x= y- 7 \lceil \frac{y-7}{1120} \rceil$.

**Note**: Erick made the observation that since $y \in E$, $\lceil \frac{y-7}{1120} \rceil = \lceil \frac{y}{1120} \rceil$, so the formula can be simplified (and clearly agrees with Erick's answer) to $x= y- 7 \lceil \frac{y}{1120} \rceil$.

Comment: @ErickWong: I'm writing it up and cooking meals at the same time :-)

Comment: Our formulas agree precisely (for integer $y$) when $y$ is in the range of $f$ :).

Comment: @ErickWong: Nice observation. I will steal that and add that to my answer!

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, and for the other people who have contributed. I'm new to this site: how can I "reward" your kindness?

Comment: Your thanks is my reward :-).

Answer (score 1):

When the denominator is large, the thing inside the ceiling will be small.  You can solve it by iteration.  First, ignore the part inside the ceiling.  That gives you a first guess for $x$, here $5555$.  Then use that and compute $7\lceil \frac {5555}{1113} \rceil=35$.  Use that to update your estimate, which becomes $5520$.  Now check that the new estimate hasn't changed the ceiling function, which it hasn't.  You are done.  If your target were $5575$, that would be your first guess, which would give $7\lceil \frac {5575}{1113} \rceil=42$.  Now the second guess is $5533$, which when fed into the ceiling gives $$7\lceil \frac {5533}{1113} \rceil=35$ so you need to update your guess one more time to $5540$.  Bingo.

Answer (score 1):

Since $159\cdot7 = 1113$, we have $\frac{160x}{159} \le y < \frac{160x}{159} + 7$, so $\frac{159(y-7)}{160} < x \le \frac{159y}{160}$.  We also know that $(y-x)/7$ is an integer, and rearranging the previous inequality gives

$$ \frac{y}{1120} \le \frac{y-x}{7} < \frac{y}{1120} + \frac{159}{160}.$$

Thus, if $y$ is actually in the range of the function we have $x = y - 7\lceil \frac{y}{1120}\rceil$.  However, as copper.hat points out, some values of $y$ are not in the range.  These are the ones where $\lceil \frac{y}{1120} \rceil - \frac{y}{1120}$ is larger than $\frac{159}{160}$, a.k.a when the remainder of $y$ mod $1120$ is between $1$ and $7$.

Comment: Sorry Eric, but isn't my hint useful for the OP. Indeed, you and Ross made a complete operation on this function. Thanks. +1

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the math skills to calculate it but, going by attempts, this seems to work... If $y=x+7\lceil\frac x {1113}\rceil$, then $x=y-7\lceil\frac {y-7} {1113}\rceil$.

Comment: Doesn't work for large $x$, say $x > 10000$.

Comment: Uh? Why? Can you gimme an example?

Comment: When $x=10000$, $y = 10063$ but your formula gives $x = 9993$.  I should have stated a larger bound than $10000$, since not every such $x$ fails.  On the other hand every $x > 2\times 10^6$ is probably a counterexample.

Comment: Ops, understood. Sorry for making you waste your time asking for an example. And the reason is pretty clear... the other formula proposed by you and some other people seems to work just fine. Many thanks!